# Remove Attributes/Points D3.js JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, d3.js

I have the following draw function:

```
function drawMap(json){ 

d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {
        states.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", data ? quantize : null)
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("title", function(d) {return "hi";});

});

data  = convertJSON(json);
}
```

I want to call the drawMap() function multiple times with a new json parameter to update the figure, but the figure doesn't get overwritten. I was wondering how I can remove/delete the previous figure so I can just plot a new figure over it? Or whether i can use the .exit() function to remove previous data points and then reload new data points?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice tutorial on how to add new and remove old data and the .enter() and .exit() selections [here](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html).